# How to get to retrieve Bytes[] from VARCHAR in Ado.Net?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to retrieve some data stored as varchar in an SQL table to bytes[] in c#.

The SQL server is running MS SQLServer 2005.
The table in question has a column defined as varchar(3900), non null.
This column is usually filled by c++ code writing different POD structures straight into the column.
Basically passing the pointer to the structure to the c++ sql code updating the table.
Different c++ programs read and write to this table and share the same headers describing those POD structures.
The type of POD structure is indicated by another column in the table. Lets call it DataType
The way the table is defined (as the column) cannot be changed. It would require a way to huge change in the currently functioning systems.

How can I get the full content (the 3900 bytes) of the varchar to Bytes[] in C#
My aim is use ADO.net to get rows from this table. Read this column and the DataType one.
Depending on DataType build an Object following the skeleton of the c++ POD structure.

Then how to write back to the table from my C# Object to the varchar(3900).

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553285/how-to-get-varchar-as-byte-using-datareader-in-ado-net) but it seems ADO.net sees this column as string and then truncate the content. I cannot seem to get the "raw" content of the varchar column.

Any idea?

Edit:

In c++
The data written to the column is declared as a `char[3901]`.
Complete POD structures are "written" over it using `memcopy`.
Before being stored in the table using ADO:
It is first converted to a WideCharString using `MultiByteToWideChar`
Then to a Bstring `BSTR` which in turn is put into a `VARIANT` and finaly used by ADO to update the table.

Comment: please show some code.. what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Varchar does not map to byte[] - it maps to char[] or (more commonly) string. This shouldn't be truncated; you should be ok to jut use regular mapping, or GetString if using a reader.

Comment: As already stated, `varchar` holds `string` data. Your actual question is how to convert some `string` (or `char[]`) to a `byte[]`. There is no simple answer without an example of before and after.

Comment: what enconding does the C++ code use?

Comment: The problem is that if your database is storing byte values as varchar strings, you're going to encounter conversion problems, especially if your data contains characters (octets) outside the range 0x00-0x7F as the data get converted from whatever encoding SQL Server is using to the UTF-16 that the CLR uses for string internally. You need to convert/cast the data to `varbinary` in SQL &mdash; see my answer for details.

Comment: Thank you all.
I tried 
`char[] buff = new char[3900];
var dataChar = dbReader.GetChars(0, 0, buff, 0, 3900);
var dataString = dbReader.GetString(0);`
I do get in both case a 'length' of 1552 for example out of the 3900.
Which is the same 'length' I get from @Nicholas Carey answer.
I guess it means that the SQL server knows where the 'useful' data ends, is that correct or do I misss some data due to some encoding.

Comment: SQL Server (and most other `varchar` implementations) implement a `varchar` as an [unsigned] 16-bit length prefix containing the length of the data, followed by that many characters of data. If you have 10 bytes of data (say, 'John Smith', it will consume 12 bytes of storage on the data page, 0x000A + 'John Smith'. `varchar(N)` specifies the **maximum** data length as `N`. When you *read* the data, of course, you do not see the length prefix (that being an internal implementation detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a table

```
create table foobar
(
  id        int           not null primary key ,
  some_text varchar(2000) not null ,
)
```

To retrieve `some_text` as octets:

```
select id = id ,
       some_octets = convert(varbinary(2000),some_text)
from foobar
```

An insert and update:

```
declare @id          int
declare @some_octets varbinary(2000)

insert foobar ( id , some_text ) values ( @id , convert(varchar(2000),@some_octets) )

update foobar set @some_text = convert(varchar(2000),@some_octets)
where id = @id
```

Comment: Thanks.
It seems to return the same number of bytes as I would get from the String reader or a char reader.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I should give the obligatory "You should be using a binary data type to store binary data..." but I am sure you know that and for what ever reason you are stuck with the `varchar` data type.

That said, here is a snippet of very basic ADO.NET code to read/write the binary data.

The code assumes that the following table exists

```
CREATE TABLE BinTest
(
   BinData varchar(3000) NOT NULL
)
```

The following code will insert a binary array of data into the table and the read it back. For arrays limited to the size of the varchar this should work with out needing to use more advanced methods to read the binary data.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,65,66,4,3,2,1,0};

    using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"<your connection string here>"))
    {
      con.Open();

      var cmd = con.CreateCommand();

      // Insert binary data into varchar
      cmd.CommandText = "insert into BinTest (BinData) values (cast(@BinData as varbinary))"; 
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BinData", bytes);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      // Read binary data from varchar
      cmd.Parameters.Clear();
      cmd.CommandText = "select cast(BinData as varbinary) from BinTest";
      using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
          if (!rdr.IsDBNull(0))
          {
            var data = rdr.GetSqlBinary(0);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data.Value));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `cast(BinData as varbinary)` was only returning 30 bytes.
However the `convert(varbinary(2000),some_text)` from @nicholas-carey [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9487015/1238350) is returning the same number of bytes (1552 in the case i tried) as the number of Char (from `var dataChar = dbReader.GetChars(0, 0, buff, 0, 3900);`) or the string length if i used `dbReader.GetString(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the encoding of the data, you may be able to use LINQ and [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kftcaf9.aspx) to handle the conversion from string to char array to byte array and back again as show in this example snippet.

```
string TestValue = "1234567890";

byte[] Result = TestValue.ToCharArray().SelectMany(item => BitConverter.GetBytes(item)).ToArray<byte>();

string BackToTestValue = new string(Result.Select((item, index) => BitConverter.ToChar(Result, Math.Min(index, Result.Length - 2))).Where((item, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToArray<char>());
```

Of course, instead of the fixed test string shown here you would use the value you read from the database. I think you've already seen how that works from other answers.